# HTML <a> local links , target="_blank" not work

Tags: html

I have this problem: when I set the "href" attribute a relative URL like:

```
<a href="/app/site/index.php" target=“_blank”>test</a>
```

it could not open the linked document in a new window or tab, but when I change the "href" to a absolute URL like:

```
<a href="http://www.ou-lee.com/app/site/index.php" target=“_blank”>test</a>
```

the "target" attribute is worked.

What's the difference between both??

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/webbrowser-app/+bug/1191830 - possibly related? Also those look like smart quotes around your target. I don't know that they are hurting, but they certainly won't be helping

Comment: are you sure your relative url is correct? you might be in a different subfolder which could require you to have to go ../app/site/index.php (as an example)

Comment: If it does not open to a new window? What does it do?

Comment: Double check your quote marks, both these samples have curly quotes, which is an invalid character.

Comment: is the anchor tag living in the root html page ? If not, then that's why you are not index.php because it does not exists in that path

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here based on the limit information you have provided:

if your html page containing the link is already in `http://www.ou-lee.com/app/site/` for instance `http://www.ou-lee.com/app/site/somepage.php`

then the relative path should just be index.php : `<a href="index.php" target=“_blank”>test</a>`

the relative path is relative to your current position (folder), not to the root domain.

Another example to make this clearer, if your current page is in `http://www.ou-lee.com/somefolder/` and you want to use a relative url to get to `app/site/index.php`. First you would have to go up one level `../` then you would go to `app/site/index.php` so your entire `href` should be: `../app/site/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="../app/site/index.php" target=“_blank”>test</a>
```

Without knowing your folder structure, I can only assume it is one step above.

Another way will be to use,

```
<base href="~/" />
```

after your title tag, so you're pointing to root, and then you can use what you had.

```
<a href="/app/site/index.php" target=“_blank”>test</a>
```